# People Hub sync with OS and android?

Tags: sync, contacts, people-hub

I have in my people hub several groups. I wonder if I buy other phone rather than a Nokia Lumia, for exemple a Samsung, a LG..., if my people hub will sync with its groups with other cell phones which use sytems link OS and android?

Answer (score 1):

People hub uses your Microsoft account. If on your next phone you use the microsoft account you were using on the windows phone, it will continue to sync (assuming that you will be using people hub on desktop since you will not have a windows phone :P)